# How to display in a table an array of object - Angular

Tags: angular, ngfor

How could I display the content of this array in a table row? I'm stuck right now...

```
cellContent = [
      {
        row1: {
          groupA: {
            col1: '100', col2: '100'
          },
          groupB: {
            col1: '100', col2: '100'
          },
          groupC: {
            col1: '100', col2: '100'
          },
          groupD: {
            col1: '100', col2: '100'
          },
          groupE: {
            col1: '100', col2: '100'
          },
          groupF: {
            col1: '100', col2: '100'
          },
          groupG: {
            col1: '3,900', col2: '3,900'
          },
        }
        row2: {more code}
      }
    ];
```

This is what I'm trying to do, but it's not working.

**html code**

```
<table>
 <tr>
     <ng-container *ngFor="let group of cellContent">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let item of group.item; let i=index">
               <td>{{item.col1}}</td>
          </ng-container>
     </ng-container>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use angular builtin keyvalue pipe to iterate an object:

```
<table>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let group of cellContent">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let row of group | keyvalue">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let subGroup of row.value | keyvalue">
        <tr>
          <td>{{subGroup.value.col1}}</td>
          <td>{{subGroup.value.col2}}</td>
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

[here is an example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2jeekm?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fmain.html)